# Facebook API: Getting a page feed vs. getting a user feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been researching, testing, searching for a large part of the day regarding the Facebook API, and I'm still unsure of how a few things work.

I'm working on creating a php plugin that connects to Facebook and pulls a user or page's wall, then displays them in a custom post feed.

I started out by setting it up to pull pages from a Facebook *page* (as opposed to a user). That was extremely easy. I created a Facebook "app" and used the App_id and app_secret to retrieve the posts using this call:

```
// Get facebook user id
$fb_page_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/reeses';

// Apparently it works if the whole page url is appended
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_page_url;

... the curl request, omitted for brevity ...

$result = json_decode($result);

// Get the user id
$fb_user_id = $result->id;

$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/' . $fb_user_id . '/feed?limit='.$this->settings['total_posts']);
```

I didn't even have to do anything with an access token. Easy! It simply pulled the posts in and I could parse them and use them.

...Then I tried to get the same thing to work with a user's wall, and everything became hard and confusing...

Here a few questions that I just can't seem to get solid answers to:

**Question 1: Is it correct that it is no longer possible to access a user's /feed without special API approval/permission from Facebook?**

From my reading, it seems that in order to access a user's feed, such as /me/feed, you need an access token which permits read_stream. It also seems that read_stream is not granted from Facebook without special permission. Given that fact, I'm thinking that it's not really practical to try to use /feed for a user.

**Question 2: Is it correct that no access token is needed to get a page's feed?**

This seems to be my experience, but again, I can't find it stated anywhere, so I'd love a solid answer.

**Question 3: Is it correct that it is an entirely different process to get a page's feed vs. getting a user's feed?**

Again, this seems to be my experience. Is there any process that works for both?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. it depends (on whether the page itself is public, or access is restricted, on the visibility of the posts, and on the API version), and 3. No.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Can you elaborate on the third one? I mean, as shown in my code snippet above, it's very easy to access a page. The same process does not work for accessing a user. What is the process that works for both?

Comment: This probably won't help, but I completely agree with CBroe's comment. Access token's are provided if the page itself is considered public of restricted through median of access.

Comment: Elaborating on 3: The _method_ of getting the feed is the same, by requesting `/page_id/feed` resp. `/user_id/feed`. They just differ in that reading a user’s feed requires `read_stream` permission, access to which will only be granted to apps on platforms that do not have a native Facebook client already, so you will not get it approved for any kind of web app. The most you can do is read the user’s own posted stuff from their respective endpoints via the individual `user_*` permissions, whereas their feed – that also includes stuff published by others – is off limits for you.

Comment: Great! If you move your comments to an answer I'll accept it! Just to clarify this as well, Facebook will not even allow me to use user_* without review and approval. Is that right?